# FCM notification on locked screen Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developing one app in that I not able to receive FCM notification when phone is locked.

```
_fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
            id: 100,
            channelKey: "basic_channel",
            title: message['notification']['title'],
            body: message['notification']['body'],
            showWhen: true,
            autoCancel: true));
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

I used firebase and Awesome Notification plugin to show notification.

Package Used : firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

Below is the code how I showing

```
   class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final pushNotificationService = PushNotificationService(_firebaseMessaging);
      pushNotificationService.initialise();
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me, I stuck here
Thank you

Comment: can you try to set the priority as high and see if that helps

Comment: post appropriate code like library used for FCM, class where you have initialised fcm receiver etc

Comment: @Quicklearner I updated the question, let me know if it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i can recommend you is change the function, you can implement something like this:

```
void subscribeChannel(String data) async =>
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(data);

void unsubscribeChannel(String channelId) async =>
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(channelId);

void listenNotificationEvents() {
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
    (value) async {
      if (value != null) setLocalNotification(value);
    },
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
    if (event.data.isNotEmpty) setLocalNotification(event);
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
    if (event.data.isNotEmpty) changeScreen(event.data);
  });
}
```

Those functions are basically to let firebase setup everything and enable also receive notifications even when the app has been killed or is on background.

and on your **MaterialApp** **class** you need to use this.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
try {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
      (message) => onBackgroundMessage(message.data));
} catch (_) {}
```

finally, if you receive a notification, and the app is open, firebase will execute everything in the block code, so the final change is to setup inside the onMessage the setup of your local notification.

Please let me know if this help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case notification received (I can hear sound) but not shown on the lock screen.
In the app settings showing notification on the lock screen was disabled by default, I enabled it and everything was ok.